# need solution for hosting php-sqlsrv application in linux(centos)

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

We developed a php webapplication in windows environment which contacts sql server remotely. Now if we try to host the same application in linux environment(Centos), it’s not connecting to sql server through my php application. Please find the below configurations..

**Windows:**

Application: PHP (version: 5.3.8)

Server: Wamp server

Database: Remotely connects to SQL Server 2008 R2

Code used to connect : sqlsrv_connect (Sql drivers installed & connected)

DLL used: all php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll files

Installed SQL Server 2012 native client also

Now how could I host my site in centos with above(configuration) mentioned php application???

**Linux(Centos):**

Even we tried with free TDS in centos. This helps in contact SQL server remotely, but our php application is not supporting for this. I understood that dll files & activating those activations plays major role to connect sql server remotely with php application. But DLL files can’t use for linux environment. So any suggestions to fix this issue?

Any suggestions/Solutions will be grateful. Thank You.

Comment: Check the output from phpinfo() on centos. Has the extension been loaded?

Comment: hi hek..thanks for prompt reply..no..it has not been loaded.. :(

Comment: Have you tried the way described in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/mssql.setup.php) ?

Comment: that documentation explains for mssql drivers hek..but we are trying for sqlsrv drivers and its php extensions which supports in linux :(

Comment: Ok, understood the difference between mssql and php_sqlsrv. (I'm not a Windows expert) ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the php_sqlsrv driver from Microsoft exists no Linux driver. From the documentation :

> **Supported Operating Systems**: Windows 2000 Service Pack 4; Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2; Windows Server 2008; Windows Small Business Server 2003 ; Windows Vista Service Pack 1; Windows XP Service Pack 2

Although the source code of the driver is available it hasn't ported to Linux yet. You have the following choices to port your web application to Linux:

- Try to use the mssql driver (if possible)
- Try to use the odbc driver (if possible)
- Migrate to a different database like mysql, postgres ...
- port the driver to Linux yourself (hard)
- Use Windows ;)

Another (**really hacky**) way (if you really need this) may be: Installing `wine` on CentOS together with running php as fcgi where the interpreter is a wine application. Then you could use the php_sqlsrv Windows dll. I've not tested this but it might work.

Comment: @smallerik Are you going the hacky fast cgi way? :)

Comment: i donno that and all hek..we need to launch an application in linux..i just send ur suggestion to admin team..they said they will look after it.. :)

Comment: Ok, understood. good luck! :)